# Enforcing reasonable values when modeling one's domain

Tags: domain-model, user-experience

Should one enforce reasonable values when modeling one's domain?

Here's an example:

Assume that we have a scheduling application that schedules visits for people who require assistance and normally one would not schedule a visit more than a maximum of a year in advance. Should I then enforce that by saying that a visit cannot be scheduled more than say three years in advance because doing so would indicate that the user did something wrong?

Intuitively I think that this would be nice and that it would maybe help prevent some users from making erroneous input. But I also believe that this comes at a cost of more complexity in the domain model, and that can sometimes be hard to model correctly.

Like, basing a behavior of some other function on the fact that there are no visits scheduled three years from now could probably be explicitly modeled but I can think of situations where a limit is based on variable, user-created entities, and that can be very hard to model.

What is your experience? And, are there any good sources out there that reason about this concept?

Comment: That sounds more like an UX issue, less like something that's core of your domain model like "every booking must be associated with at least one available assistant". I do sometimes introduce artificial limits in order to make the system work predictably, but I try to avoid preventing things that might actually be correct.

Comment: In response to the close vote; I think this question is on-topic. Not to discuss the specific rule that OP may be thinking of (this is way too dependent on a specific scenario), but we can address the kinds of considerations that go into this aspect of software design. In saying that, the last paragraph should be rephrased or removed, since it's asking for anecdotal experiences and external resources, both of which are off-topic.

Answer (score 4):

This is subjective. The boundary of our software is defined as behavior, and the question is what you find reasonable behavior of your codebase.

Personally, I am of the "shit goes in, shit comes out, not my problem" line of thinking. If consumers input unreliable values, then the output is going to be unreliable, and that's not a problem I (or my codebase) created.

But this assumes that the blast radius of bad input only blows back on the source of the bad input. When it starts affecting others, this is where validation start being relevant. Not because it protects the consumer, but because it protects *us* (i.e. my codebase, and my ownership).

Based on your example scenario, the blast radius seems to be focused on the consumer, so I'll stick to that scenario.

> Should I then enforce that by saying that a visit cannot be scheduled more than say three years in advance because doing so would indicate that the user did something wrong?

Following what I just said, the first question would be: what is the impact *on you* that the consumer is entering a date in the relatively distant future?

If there's no negative impact, arguably you can stop your train of thought right here, at least from a *domain* design perspective (UX design is a different topic of conversation).

> **Assume** that [..] **normally** one would not schedule a visit more than a maximum of a year in advance.

Given that you posted this on *SoftwareEngineering*.SE, I'm going to assume that your role is one of software engineer in a larger team. Different roles have different responsibilities and without additional context I'm going to assume your role is restricted to that of a software engineer.

What you're doing here is deciding what is normal and what is not. Generally speaking, this is not your remit as an engineer. The product owner or business analyst tends to be the source of how the application should behave, and as a developer you should be figuring out how to provide the requested behavior rather than dreaming up additional requirements.

Secondly, a YAGNI argument is very easy to make here. If you don't build the added validation, either this is perfectly fine, or you're going to run into concrete complaints about a lack of safeguards, at which point you can still introduce this additional validation, but this time it will have been vetted by the product owner/business analyst.

Comparatively, if you immediately introduce this additional validation, you increased the codebase complexity and run the risk of wasting effort on a feature that was never even requested in the first place. This is not an efficient software development process.

We can also then ask ourself where we draw the line. How about weekend days? Public holidays? Night time?

There's a lot that you can *argue* can be excluded, but is it really necessary  to do so, and is it really your place to argue? Maybe it is if you're the product owner, but most software development is done by someone who themselves does not call the shots on expected application behavior.

Furthermore, I can argue that adding this additional validation inherently means restricting the utility of your software, which would now require more coding and redeploying effort if your arbitrary "too far in the future" rule no longer applies.

Good coding practices generally push you towards lowering the amount of reasons for needing to make changes (and minimizing the amount of changes you need to make) specifically because extra effort is pointless if it could be avoided.

Really, it boils down to "this is more work, and more complexity. Do we need to?", and this question needs to be asked to whoever is authorized to answer it. Make sure to explain the consequences of the answer being "yes", as this is not a cost-free decision (time, effort, complexity all ramp up the effective cost to the business in staff wages).